# How to insert a specific character in already exists columns data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a column that contains numbers and letters. Ex: a5c648a6. I need to add the following character `:` after every pair of characters and insert the modified one into another column. i.e, the output supposed to be ike: a5:c6:48:a. Note that I don't need to add `:` after the last character.

Comment: you're creating MAC ID from the text eh? You need to create a stored proc, take the text into a variable and insert : after every two chars. Once completely done you can remove last char IF it's a :

Comment: Do you want to update existing column or add values with ':'?

Comment: @Somnath Muluk: I need to insert values with ':' in a new column.

Comment: @Somnath - He says he wants to insert the modified value into another column.

Comment: You need a function for that. depends the language you use

Comment: @JuryA Which language do you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

Create the following function in your mysql database:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION insert2(str text, pos int, delimit varchar(124))
RETURNS text
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE str_len INT;
DECLARE out_str text default '';
SET str_len=length(str);
WHILE(i<str_len) DO
SET out_str=CONCAT(out_str, SUBSTR(str, i,pos), delimit);
SET i=i+pos; 
END WHILE;
-- trim delimiter from end of string
SET out_str=TRIM(trailing delimit from out_str);
RETURN(out_str);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then execute the function with the string that you want to convert to a MAC address:

```
select insert2('a5c648a6',2,':')
```

You can now replace the `'a5c648a6'` with a database column field name and run the function to convert the strings.